# convert json_encode value to javascript array

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am send an array of php by json_encode to javascript. this is the array after encoding

```
"[{\"albumid\":\"ASaBFzCtl8\",\"albumname\":\"anni\",\"type\":\"3\",\"access\":\"2\",\"itemcount\":\"2\"},{\"albumid\":\"EmgsZ43ehT\",\"albumname\":\"testalbum\",\"type\":\"1\",\"access\":\"1\",\"itemcount\":\"0\"},{\"albumid\":\"Jf4H4SvFGk\",\"albumname\":\"test2album\",\"type\":\"3\",\"access\":\"1\",\"itemcount\":\"0\"},{\"albumid\":\"k3pacBSmIl\",\"albumname\":\"testalbumpvt\",\"type\":\"3\",\"access\":\"2\",\"itemcount\":\"0\"}]"
```

on javascript i used jquery.parse(data) but still not get an array.what can i do .i need  type value out of it

Comment: do you want to decode it?

Comment: How did you get that output? Was that an echo from PHP? It would help if you could post the function or at least the relevant lines of code which deal with the json_encode and its output.

Comment: try JSON.parse(yourString);

Comment: Try `jQuery.parseJSON(data);` ? Can you post your javascript code ?

Comment: It's `JSON.parse()` not `jQuery.parse()`, [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: You don't send an array of PHP to js, you make an HTTP request from the browser to your server, with eventually answers with a JSON string. You have then to parse it via the aforementioned `JSON.parse`. Think in protocols, not languages.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your PHP is generating JavaScript code, you do this:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode(yourPhpArray); ?>;
```

`json_encode` returns a JSON string. JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal notation, and so you can drop JSON into JavaScript code directly anywhere an expression is valid (such as after the `=` in an assignment, as above). No need for `JSON.parse` or `$.parseJSON` (and in fact, using them would fail).

`x` will either be a JavaScript object (if the PHP "associative" array has non-numeric keys, and so `json_encode` output `{...}`) or a JavaScript array (if `json_encode` output `[...]`).

If, on the other hand, you're returning *just* the JSON (not generating JavaScript code), perhaps in reply to an ajax request, then if you're using jQuery to query it, jQuery will parse the result for you. If you're doing XHR directly, you'll need to parse the result (e.g., `var x = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to decode/parse it on client side use :

```
JSON.parse(yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.parseJSON() returns an object, instead of an array

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

You can use

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(...);
var myValue = obj.myValue;
```

instead of obj['myValue']